Spring Boot Webflux (v3.1.0): `@ControllerAdvice` Handle Multi-Status Response + Exception
I'm trying to determine if using @ControllerAdvice is appropriate to use to handle request that could have multiple http statuses (HTTP 207 Multi-Status). I have an existing API that includes several request that uses HTTP status 207. These particular request interact with an another application API so we capture that of those request and pass it along with the response status from our service. I'm wondering can @ControllerAdvice handle scenarios like this.

Spring does not support directly. Every http request has only one response status regardless of technology. Except the WebDAV protocol.
